# How long do the certificates generated on AWS IoT Core last?

Tags: ssl, iot, esp8266, client-certificates, aws-iot

I was working on my project using esp8266 and AWS IoT Core, but while running the program it shows the following error related to the certificate in the serial monitor...

```
Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
WiFiClientSecure SSL error: Chain could not be linked to a trust anchor.

Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
WiFiClientSecure SSL error: Chain could not be linked to a trust anchor.

Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
WiFiClientSecure SSL error: Chain could not be linked to a trust anchor.

Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
WiFiClientSecure SSL error: Chain could not be linked to a trust anchor.

Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
WiFiClientSecure SSL error: Chain could not be linked to a trust anchor.

Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
WiFiClientSecure SSL error: Chain could not be linked to a trust anchor.

Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
WiFiClientSecure SSL error: Chain could not be linked to a trust anchor.

Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
WiFiClientSecure SSL error: Chain could not be linked to a trust anchor.
```

At times it also shows that the certificate has expired for some reason, and I end up making a new one every 2 months. Can someone pls help solve this issue?

Is there a limit to when the certificates last?

Comment: Can you connect at all or is this an intermittent problem? If it is a persistent connection issue then can you share your code?

Otherwise, I'm not sure if this helps but I have noticed that the AWS IoT core endpoint rotates IP address. So after some time if you are using the same IP address then a connection will stop working.

Comment: Read https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/BearSSL_CertStore/BearSSL_CertStore.ino, particular the comment at the begin of the sketch. In summary, use the CA root cert.